# Laravel: How to define relations while the primary key of the model is changed to slug?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, many-to-many

I like to define Many To Many Polymorphic Relations like the one that is mentioned in laravel documentation, but with one difference that I like the primary key to be changed to slug. I do that in the model by `protected $primaryKey = 'slug'` but when I do that I can not retrieve relations anymore. I guess I must change the arguments of `morphToMany` and `morphedByMany` method to fix this. However, I don't know how should I do that.
I would appreciate your help.

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string
    slug - string (primary key)

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried with your models?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks like.

```
// morphToMany($related, $name, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null,
                            $relatedPivotKey = null, $parentKey = null,
                            $relatedKey = null, $inverse = false)
```

So try this one in your Post model.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
         return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable', null, null, 'taggable_id');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. it face an error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'slug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `tag_id` from `taggables` where `slug` = 8 and

Comment: okay,

try moving the slug between the 2 nulls.

return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable', null, 'slug' );

or 


return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable', 'slug' );

and let me know whats the output.

Comment: When you post something and your taggables.taggable_id  row saved the slug from post?

Comment: when I post something everything is fine. and taggables table is filled as it is supposed to. The thing is it is based on id, however, Post primary-key is a slug (string) and that is why I can not retrieve relationship. when I try to retrieve relationship the result is empty.

Comment: it does not save the slug from the post. I tried by changing the field type and name to taggable_slug (string).

Comment: Okay, you need to save the slug to your taggables.taggable_id and so after that you can retrieve the correct posts by using this return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable', null, null, 'taggable_id');